# ** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: :eacces - Building release with MIX_ENV=prod

Tags: node.js, elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix, exrm

I am not sure where to put that error, elixir, phoenixframework, or nodejs.

I am trying to create my first release build with elxir and phoenix. During the release build I see the following error. I am just not sure if this is a version/dependency problem or something that has to do with nodejs since the only information I could find related to eacces was in relationship with nodejs. Is there anything I am missing in my configuration?

Here is the error stack:

```
Building release with MIX_ENV=prod.
** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: :eacces
lib/exrm/utils/utils.ex:110: ReleaseManager.Utils.relx/5
lib/mix/tasks/release.ex:341: anonymous fn/4 in   Mix.Tasks.Release.do_release/1
lib/ex_unit/capture_io.ex:146: ExUnit.CaptureIO.do_capture_io/2
lib/ex_unit/capture_io.ex:119: ExUnit.CaptureIO.do_capture_io/3
lib/mix/tasks/release.ex:340: Mix.Tasks.Release.do_release/1
lib/mix/tasks/release.ex:78: Mix.Tasks.Release.do_run/1
(mix) lib/mix/task.ex:296: Mix.Task.run_task/3
(mix) lib/mix/cli.ex:58: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

My environment is as follows:

```
$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Elixir 1.3.4

$ npm --version
3.10.8
```

I run in a few version problems after adding exrm which I solved by adding to my dependencies the following:

```
 {:exrm, git: "git://github.com/bitwalker/exrm.git"},
 {:relx, github: "erlware/relx", override: true},
 {:erlware_commons, github: "erlware/erlware_commons", override: true},
 {:cf, "~> 0.2.1", override: true}
```

Three hours later...

I have created a fresh phoenix project using mix and could reproduce the problem. Once I added exrm I got the same error. I switchen then to distillery to see the same error. I created an issue on distillery with the hope to get there a solution. [Issue 142 on distillery](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/issues/142)

---

EDIT:

Additional details on this issue from the distillery report:

$ uname -a
Darwin Andreass-MBP. 16.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0: Thu Oct 13 21:26:57 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3789.21.3~60/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

I am at least four levels deep in a development tree that is fully owned by my account, under my home folder.

Comment: Look at this page. http://erlang.org/doc/man/file.html specifically search for eaccess. You'll see the most likely cause is insufficient permissions.  Tell us the OS, etc. etc. We can't offer intelligent suggestions without details.

Comment: You're sure that you're not getting issues from Erlang itself?  I see some notes about running Erlang on MacOSX (Jaguar) here: http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R9C-0.readme  You may want to insure that Erlang is working correctly.

Comment: Runs ok with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

This error is caused by a permission denied when attempt to write some artifact of build. You need to override EXRM with distilery and check files/directory permissions.

**Long explanation**

Error `eacces` means permission denied in Unix systems, ie, when your release task was attempting to write some builded file, this receives a permission denied from OS.

The `CaseClauseError` indicates that possibilty is not handled by case clausule in EXRM source code.

Anyway, EXRM was deprecated, and you need overide it with [distillery](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery)